# Rules forms with node reference fields

Tags: forms, nodes, rules

I have content-A (Events) and Content-B (registration to the Events) which has node-ref field referencing content-B to content-A.
Content-A has selection field-A and Content-B has some other fields witch I need to show or hide on form load (when adding or editing content-B) depending on content-A field-A selection.
If i try to use rules event: 'Content-B node form is being built' - I cannot use Conditions to search for Content-A fields value. I tried other events like before content is being saved but then I can't change fields conditions.

Can anyone tell me what is best solution to achieve this task?
thanks for any help ..